# How to perform a diarization using ALIZE LIA_SpkSeg for 'any codec data'?

Tags: speech-recognition

**I'd like to use any type codec file(g711 u-law, g729a, 16kHz/16bit ...) for ALIZE LIA_SpkSeg diarization tool.**

Already, I understood the setting method about input sph file for each codec(sampling rate) using SPRO.
Next steps, **should I make UBM(speech, music etc) for each codec type?
Or Can I use default UBM including the LIA_SpkSeg for all codec type data?**

If I need make the UBMs, how can I make it?

Please let me know about it.